# Salesforce regex get everything between '(' and ') brace repeatedly?

Tags: regular-expressions

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile('\\((.*?)\\)');
string subject=  '( A  =  123 AND B  =  123 ) OR ( C  =  123 )' ;

Matcher matcher = p.matcher(subject);
system.debug(matcher.group(0));  // Saying no match found
```

I tried the regex here at http://regexr.com/ but it's not working.

Comment: you want something `A  =  123 AND B  =  123  OR  C  =  123 ` in output?

Comment: I think you need to call matches() first to actually apply regular expression to string (like matcher.matches() ). documentation -- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_pattern_and_matcher_using.htm

Comment: @Tushar sharma  -  I am expect to get value 1->   A =123 and B= 123   and value 2 ->  c =123

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you retrieve the `group` results, you must call `find`. Also I think `0` corresponds to the entire expression group, so you probably want `group(1)`.

```
while (matcher.find()) system.debug(matcher.group(1));
```